# Oracle: select week of the year according to an input list

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I had a two tables who looks like:

```
Table A:

  ORG_DATE
03/04/2018
02/10/2019
17/12/2018

Table B:

Start_date   End_Date     Week_of_Yr
01/04/2018  08/04/2018    2018041
01/10/2019  08/10/2019    2019101
14/12/2018  21/12/2018    2018123
```

The goal is to achieve a table who looks like:

```
  ORG_DATE      Week_of_Yr
03/04/2018       2018041
02/10/2019       2019101
17/12/2018       2018123
```

Simply assign the correct week of the year when the field ORG_DATE from table A, falls between start_date and end_date of table B.

So far i tried the following because there aren't fields for making a possible join between the tables:

```
SELECT 
Week_of_Yr
FROM TABLE B
WHERE TO_DATE((SELECT 
               TO_CHAR(A11.ORG_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') ORG_DATE
               FROM TABLE_A A11
               GROUP BY A11.ORG_DATE), 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN Start_date AND End_Date;
```

However, the query doesn't accept a list as an input. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join them checking the `org_date` falls in between the `start_date` and `end_date` in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT a.org_date,
       b.week_of_yr
       FROM a
            LEFT JOIN b
                      ON b.start_date <= a.org_date
                         AND b.end_date > a.org_date;
```